# bash create user with password: password not set as expected

Tags: bash, authentication, passwords, ubuntu-16.04

In I want to set a username and password non-interactively, but the password is not getting set correctly.

*create_user.sh*

```
user=username
pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
echo $user $pass
useradd -m -p $pass $user
```

*In the terminal:*

```
$ sudo ./create_user.sh
username pa8fg5oAyLo8g
$ tail -1 /etc/passwd
username:x:1004:1004::/home/username:
$ su - username
Password: password
su: Authentication failure
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE

This works, but it prints `username password` to the terminal window, which may not be desirable, and it requires hard-coded values:

*create_user.sh*

```
user=username
pass=password
useradd -m username
echo 'username:password' | chpasswd
```

*In the terminal:*

```
$ sudo ./create_user.sh
username password
$ su - username
Password: password
username@hostname:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was wrong. Here is a working version:

*create_user.sh*

```
user=username
pass=password
salt=Az # or any 2-character string from [A-za-z]
# Encrypt the password
pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], $salt)' $pass)
echo $user $pass
useradd -p $pass -m $user
```

*In the terminal:*

```
$ sudo ./create_user.sh
username AzSzB2uy8JFlk
$ su - username
Password: password
username@hostname:~$
```